# How can i capture a tag value in Soap response in SoapUI, and write it in Excel

Tags: excel, soap, groovy, soapui

I have used POI to read from Excel, Now im trying to capture the response and write it back on Excel, here is the Code

```
 <AtomicWeight>1.00797</AtomicWeight>
```

i want to take 1.00797 from respond write it in excel. But this tag is not exist in request. is there any way i can achieve that?

//Response Message

---

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetAtomicWeightResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetAtomicWeightResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
 // want to capture this value(1.00797) and write it in excel
   <AtomicWeight>1.00797</AtomicWeight>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>]]></GetAtomicWeightResult>
      </GetAtomicWeightResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Perhaps have a read through [ask].

Comment: I have use Groovy to read data from Excel  to paramiterize the request. i need to capture 1 tag value from response, and i wanted to write it in excel. i was wondering if there is any command like getattribute or gettext like java in SoapUI.

Comment: can we achieve this by using transfer property?

Answer (score 0):

Getting to the `AtomicWeight` element is tricky because it's wrapped in CDATA. [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#_processing_xml) won't parse into it. But you can get to it by...

1. parsing the entire SOAP envelope
2. grabbing the `GetAtomicWeightResult` element and converting to a
   String
3. parsing the `GetAtomicWeightResult` String-ified element.
4. grabbing the `AtomicWeight` element.

## How to do it

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

def text = '''<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetAtomicWeightResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetAtomicWeightResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
 // want to capture this value(1.00797) and write it in excel
   <AtomicWeight>1.00797</AtomicWeight>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>]]></GetAtomicWeightResult>
      </GetAtomicWeightResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
def cdata = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml.Body.GetAtomicWeightResponse.GetAtomicWeightResult.toString())

assert cdata.Table.AtomicWeight == 1.00797
```